# Advanced Hailstone - Nested loop / combination

Tags: python, loops, nested

Generating a hailstone sequence that follows the pattern below:

if x is even -> x/2
if x is odd -> [a]x+[b]

where a and b are integer values {0,...,10}, allowing for 121 possible combinations of a and b. I need to list whether the sequence converges for all 1000 x values

I am using python to solve the problem, I'm a beginner at coding with python but am a quick learner and need guidance on how to resolve

```
`for n in range(1,1001):
for i in a:
    for j in b:
         while  j != 1 & i != 1:
             print ("a:", i, "b:", j)
             if j % 2 == 0:
                 j = j / 2
                 length = length + 1
             else:
                n = (n * j) + i     
             if n == 1:
                print (n)
```

'

the above works in that it runs but it doesn't do what I want. It just keeps looping integer one and wont move past it

Answer (score 0):

I see following problems in your code:

- `range` usage, `range` does not accept `list` as argument, you should use `for i in a:` when `a` is `list`, rework all your `for`s accordingly.
- broken `while` syntax: you have too many `:`s in your `while`, should be one `:` (at end)
- possibly broken indentation: note that `if` is not aligned with corresponding `else`, keep in mind that in Python language indentation is crucial
- `j = j / b` will produce error - you can't divide `int` by `list`
- you never define `n`, thus `n = (n * a) + 1` and all other lines with `n`, will produce errors

Keep in mind that my list of problems might be incomplete

Answer (score 0):

'a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
b = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for n in range(1,1001):
    for i in a:
        for j in b:
             while  j != 1 & i != 1:
                 print ("a:", i, "b:", j)
                 if j % 2 == 0:
                     j = j / 2
                     length = length + 1
                 else:
                    n = (n * j) + i
                 if n == 1:
                    print (n)'

updates...I want to still be able to understand when it converges and it won't move to the next value